# Objective C - NSthread & NSAutoreleasePool?

Tags: objective-c, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

What is the best way to write a thread safe method?

I have the following method, sometimes i want to call it asynchronously (call it through a thread)
And sometimes i want to call it directly on the main thread.
Is there a problem with keeping the pool (alloc, release) even if I am not calling the method on a separate thread?

```
- (void)doStuff
{
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
     //do some stuff here?
     [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Whether or not you have a pool is such a minuscule detail amongst the elephant in the room that is the question; "How do I write a thread safe method?"   The # of details in answering **that** could make for an entire StackOverflow tag in and of itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no problem with always using your own, method-local pool. You should be using `[pool drain]` instead of `[pool release]`, though.

Comment: To clarify, `[pool drain]` and `[pool release]` are identical under manual memory management, but under GC, the former triggers a collection and the latter is a no-op.

Comment: Correct, but I see no reason not to always prefer `-drain` to `-release` for all development targeting 10.4 or later.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly safe to call on the main thread. NSAutoreleasePool maintains a stack, so in this case you're just putting a new pool on top of the stack, then popping it off when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what it would mean for the release pool, I would not recommend writing it this way. If you absolutely have to be able to call the method from the main and from other threads, code it like this:

```
- (void) doSomething {
}

- (void) doSomethingInBackground {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self doSomething];
    [pool release]
}
```

This way you wrap the method in a method that takes care of the release pool.

Answer (score 0):

I will also prefer the method mentioned by Ivo Jansch. Creating/draining a pool is valid but it may be a bit headache when you call the method doStuff: recursively or many times. But by following Ivo's method you can do stuff without a memory headache.
And also for a method to be thread safe you must use locks or @synchronized() whenever its needed, usually when accessing a array/buffer/dictionary. Your method should be something like this

```
- (void)doStuff{
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

 @synchronized(lock) 
 {
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
 }
 [pool release];}
```